# does return command invalid in plsql exception handling?

Tags: exception, plsql, return

i had reviewed plsql code written by somebody else , i figured out he use return commands in exception block, i already read in java programming this is not good practice, i also check some exception example of plsql and see that return is not used , so does anybody could confirm this is invalid?

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    create_log (  p_caller_user, 'E', '4', NULL
                , 'INTEREST_CALCULATION_TOOLS', 'CALCULATE_INTEREST'
                , V_SPY_COUNTER
                , 'UNEXPECTED ERROR DURING FUNCTION EXECUTION, ACC NO : '
                  || ',' || SQLERRM()
                  || p_account_id, SQLCODE(), SYSDATE);
    RETURN -2;
```

Comment: What does the manual say regarding this matter?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the manual is not written anything about this subject.

Comment: PLSQL functions return a value, either a number or some other object type. RETURN -2; works in a function that returns a number datatype from a function. Procedures do not do that, they do not return some sort of value. Two things to remember - plsql is old, and based on concepts from ADA programming; plsql is not java.   Return inside an exception block is okay from within in a plsql function.  What you are thinking about is static "complexity" of code  - it increases with multiple returns.  Does not really apply the same way to plsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is out of context so it's impossible to say if there is some problems or not. The code snippet is probably reporting the error condition correctly in the context (by `create_log`-procedure) even it is this case in `others` exception handler (that might be a sign of problems and according to Tom Kyte [it's for sure](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1270688200346183091)).

In general I see no issues returning from PL/SQL function non-`others` exception handler.

Oracle PL/SQL documentation says nothing about the subject:

- [Subprogram Parts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/subprograms.htm#LNPLS653)
- [RETURN Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99897)
- [Continuing Execution After Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/errors.htm#LNPLS851)

I use the following pattern routinely to return default values when optional value is not found:

```
create or replace function f1 return dual.dummy%type is
  v_dummy dual.dummy%type;
begin
  select dummy into v_dummy from dual where dummy = 'Y';

  return v_dummy;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return 'Z';
end;
/
```

(Note that I only process well known error cases where I know how the situation should be handled.)

I find the alternative way unnecessary verbose, though it will please return-once purists:

```
create or replace function f2 return dual.dummy%type is
  v_dummy dual.dummy%type;
begin
  begin
    select dummy into v_dummy from dual where dummy = 'Y';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      v_dummy := 'Z';
  end;

  return v_dummy;
end;
/
```

Compiling the functions with all warnings turned on return only the following non-related warnings:

```
Warning: PLW-06015: parameter PLSQL_DEBUG is deprecated; use PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 1
Warning(1,1): PLW-05018: unit F1 omitted optional AUTHID clause; default value DEFINER used
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not give any error it is not at all a good coding practice to do so...
Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm

It clearly specifies "The executable part contains statements, which are placed between the keywords BEGIN and EXCEPTION (or END). One or more RETURN statements must appear in the executable part of a function. The exception-handling part contains exception handlers, which are placed between the keywords EXCEPTION and END."

So here even though it doesn't give any problems for now, you shouldn't do this.. I hope this helps.